# How can I extend my Custom API where the API use enum and switch in Swift

Tags: swift

I am looking to know how could I extend my API in extension, here is my code and working:

```
enum ColorName: String, CaseIterable {
    case black, white, gray
}

struct CustomColor: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable {
    
    var color: Color
    
    static let black: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .black)
    static let white: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .white)
    static let gray: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .gray)
    
    var description: String {
        switch self.color {
        case .black: return ColorName.black.rawValue
        case .white: return ColorName.white.rawValue
        case .gray: return ColorName.gray.rawValue
        default:
            return "Not defined color name!"
        }
    }
}
```

use case:

```
let customColor1: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .black)
print(customColor1.description)  // prints: black

let customColor2: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .red)
print(customColor2.description)  // prints: not defined color name!
```

So as you can see my API does not know about color red! I want extend my API that be able to recognize the red color as well and I want make it in extensions.

```
// Extending API in extensiones ...

extension CustomColor {

    // code here to add color red ...

    static let red: CustomColor = CustomColor(color: .red)
    

    // making description for color red ...

    // var description: String { }

}


extension ColorName {

    // code here to add color red ...
    
     case red
    
}
```

But Xcode complain about `Enum 'case' is not allowed outside of an enum` I was wondering, which approach should I take to be able to make extending possible.

Comment: You cannot extend enums by adding cases.

Comment: Ok, which ways I got to make the goal possible, I am not forcing myself to use the codes in question, I am looking for expendable approach. What is used in same situation in developing an API?

Comment: Static properties like in `CustomColor` are good approach.

Comment: Thanks I could be able add red as static constant, But having an enum in coding makes thing much easy and clean. You mean I must replace enum with something else?

Comment: For example look at Apple's [`NSNotification.Name`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name) struct

Comment: @vadian: I know about notification and also I know about use case of it, but what is relationship of your link with my issue, I do not get it.

Comment: It's not about `Notification` itself, it's the way of an encapsulated nested struct with static properties which can be extended. There are other examples like `NSImage.Name` and also something like  `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier`.

Comment: @vadian: I really cannot follow you there, maybe an example could help. Ps: I got a new idea about new approach, I was thinking to add another variable in struct of CustomColor  like this: `var nameOfColor: String` and using that string for description without switch and without enum. what you think? And if some one whats can extend my API in extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your CustomColor type is almost there. If you mean the list to be extensible, that's not an enum wrapping as struct, it's just a struct. So for example:

```
struct CustomColor: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable {

    let nameOfColor: String
    let color: Color

    var description: String { nameOfColor }

    static let black = CustomColor(nameOfColor: "black", color: .black)
    static let white = CustomColor(nameOfColor: "white", color: .white)
    static let gray  = CustomColor(nameOfColor: "gray", color: .gray)
}


// Your use case. Note slightly different syntax
let customColor1 = CustomColor.black
print(customColor1)  // prints: black

// And CustomColor can be extended
extension CustomColor {
    static let red: CustomColor(nameOfColor: "red", color: .red)

}
    
let customColor2 = CustomColor.red
print(customColor2)  // prints: red
```

As vadian notes in the comments, this is exactly the pattern `Notification.Name` uses.

That said, it's not quite clear how this is doing anything more than just Color (perhaps you have more code?) For example, I can ake out `nameOfColor` and it simplifies to:

```
struct CustomColor: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable {

    let color: Color

    var description: String { color.description }

    static let black = CustomColor(color: .black)
    static let white = CustomColor(color: .white)
    static let gray  = CustomColor(color: .gray)
}
```

But then `CustomColor` isn't doing very much (but again, maybe you have more code you're not showing).

Comment: So is your answer an example of what vadian mentioned?

Comment: I was thinking to add another variable in struct of CustomColor like this: `var nameOfColor: String` and using that string for description without switch and without enum. So what is the deference of my idea and your approach?

Comment: I have no idea how you made your codes, but I cannot reuse it, for example: `struct TestType: RawRepresentable { var rawValue: String; var value: String }` code broke with this error `Type 'TestType' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'`

Comment: Lastly I wanted add that you changed my question! Where is Color gone? I cannot draw color with String, I need `var color: Color` also you did not show the way that how you are going read `var color: Color` to describe the name of Color, I am doing it in switch. How you are going to do it?

Comment: Sorry; I misread how you were using Color. That's trivially fixable. Updated. You just need to have both in the struct.

Comment: I just asked my question in very simple form but in the same time I made a mistake in asking my question, I am comparing color value in switch not the custom type! I am sorry about it, that was my mistake when I was creating example code from big project. I am going to update my question. The right code is `switch self.color` not `switch self` And that is why you can find Switch and Enum in my question title. The reason of using color in switch is covering same color in deferent initialization, like `UIColor.black == RGBA: 0001`